How can scams involving cryptocurrencies like Ethereum, Bitcoin be reported?
How can scams involving cryptocurrencies like Ethereum, Bitcoin be reported? My brother presently got hacked and lost all his funds. How do scammers perceive and pick their victims? Is there a medium to stay safe.

This post might be helpful.

Countries have specialized units to deal with online crimes or technology related. Try contacting them to report the hack. Scammers do not select victims in particular they try with anyone and those that aren't careful with their wallets are the most likely to fall in the scam.

One of the most important things one can do to protect themselves and other people from fraudulent activity is to report scams involving cryptocurrencies such as Ethereum and Bitcoin. We can help fight fraud and shield individuals from similar schemes by taking action against scams. But it's crucial to keep in mind that awareness, research, and circumspection are the best lines of protection against cryptocurrency scam. It's encouraging to know that we can make everyone's environment safer by being watchful and taking the appropriate action to report scammers. Never forget that every action matters and that, when combined, we can change things.
It can be difficult to recover money lost in a cryptocurrency scam or fraud, but there are steps you can take: report the incident to the authorities, get legal counsel, hire a cryptocurrency investigator (keep in mind that you should only hire an investigator who is willing to finish the investigation and ask for payment; from personal experience, I am strongly against upfront fees because the two times I tried to pay up front, it turned out to be a scam). It may be slightly difficult, but if you stick to your principles and do your study, you will undoubtedly find one or roll consults limited can assist you they were helpful when my wallet has hacked. You can also consider looking into possible rehabilitation techniques. But because cryptocurrencies are anonymous and decentralized, recovery isn't assured.

Scammers often target vulnerable people online, often on social media and dating apps. They use various techniques to deceive their victims, including emotional triggers, isolation, quick decisions, and trust. The scammer trolls social media platforms seeking single women, particularly older ones, and sends out dozens of friend requests. Most of these friends are vulnerable and emotionally needy, possibly recently widowed.
The scammer then sends out poems, pictures of roses, and country music links to a few dozen at a time. He may tell the victim that he has to go on a business trip to a dangerous country for a final job, which will make him and the victim rich. He soon asks for a money card for a modest amount to verify his gullibility and likely to give him more. He may also ask to book airfares, but they have to be booked through his "agent" in some faraway state. Even if you say you can book the ticket much cheaper through a search engine, he is not interested.
Scammers are always on the prowl for their next target, and unfortunately, they have a keen sense of who to go after. One major way they choose their victims is by looking for people who are vulnerable or in desperate situations. They are experts at swooping in and taking advantage of your vulnerabilities. Another way scammers choose their victims is by preying on people who are easily swayed by promises of quick money or unrealistic opportunities. They also often target individuals who may not be tech-savvy or unfamiliar with common online scams, exploiting ignorance and lack of awareness to manipulate their victims into falling for their schemes.
